# Extending NetSuite's default business logic

Tags: netsuite

I am new to NetSuite and am trying to get an understanding of how it works in the area of business rules.  So sorry if these are questions with obvious answers.

I understand a user/consultant can extend/customize it to fit with my business needs.

My questions therefore are:

1. Presumably a default instance of NetSuite contains various business
   rules that will fit some business needs.  As a user/consultant can
   you view this default business logic?
2. Can a consultant change the core business logic? Or is it more a case of adding code before and after the default logic fires?
3. Is the default business logic/rules written in SuiteScript, or is SuiteScript only used by 3rd parties when extending/overriding the default logic?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We cannot view the code that governs the default NetSuite logic and business rules, but the NetSuite Help documentation has a ton of information about how vanilla NetSuite works. All users can view and study the Help files to become more familiar with NetSuite and its default processes.
2. We cannot change the default code, but we can absolutely add code before and after many different events.
3. The default business logic is written in SuiteScript, but again, we cannot view that code. Third parties utilize SuiteScript to extend the default NetSuite functionality.

SuiteScript is not the only option for customizing NetSuite. There is also SuiteFlow, which provides users with the capability of graphically building workflows to define business rules based on user actions. No code is required (though under the covers, workflows essentially build hidden SuiteScript). There are several things that can only be accomplished in workflows and not in SuiteScript, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Netsuite's ERP, CRM, eCommerce modules have predefined standard rules which are acccording to industry standard. But customers have sometimes different business needs. For that we can customize Netsuite. There are various customization tools available in Netsuite. It supports to extend standard functionality as well as implement our custom logic. It provides suite scripts,a java script based API which can be used in almost every where in Netsuite for customization. Along with that it provides UI based customization in the form of SuiteBuilder. We can fire script before any standard business logic, after standard business logic run. We can add client side validations, schedule our application to trigger at specific time and many more. The standard business logic is written by Netsuite, we cant alter them, we cant see the code. It is the way it works. If you are new to Netsuite, it is suggested to read netsuite help guide. There is no online help other than Netsuite available. So you must go through them. If you have other query, feel free to ask.